# Problemas con Django, al instalar el plugin cymysql para conectar con la base de datos

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, django, linux

Lo que estoy utilizando:

- Sistema operativo: Debian 9
- Base de datos: MySQL 5.5
- Django 1.11.4

Ejecuto el comando:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Se muestra el siguiente mensaje de error en la terminal:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql_cymysql' isn't an 

available database backend.

Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Error was: No module named cymysql
```

Al momento de instalar `cymysql` con el comando:

```
pip install cymysql
```

Si ejecuto en modo `root` muestra:

```
Requirement already satisfied: cymysql in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.
```

En `pip freeze` tengo instalado

```
django-cymysql==2.0.0
```

No aparece instalado `cymysql`.

El archivo `settings.py` esta configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql_cymysql',
        'NAME': 'nombre_base_de_datos',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

El contenido de`models.py` es:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Formulario(models.Model):
  # parametros
  # parametros
  # parametros
```

Comment: Estas utilizando entorno virtual ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo te propongo que utilices mysqlclient==1.3.12 que sirve tanto para maridb y mysql:

`pip instal mysqlclient==1.3.12`

Luego en el settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'tubasededatos',
        'USER': 'tuusuario',
        'PASSWORD': 'tupassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS' :  { 
            'init_command' :  "SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'" , 
        }, 
    }
}
```

Si no estas utilizando virtualenv te lo recomiendo ya que puedes trabajar con multiples proyectos de django con diferentes versiones en una misma computadora.

Comment: Genial!,funciona correctamente ahora,aclaro reinstale pip y luego use mysqlclient==1.3.12.

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te haya funcionado :D!

Comment: bien ahí Piero! gusto de verte por estos lares de la red. Un abrazo bro!

Comment: Gracias Fredy ( UPAO <3 )